# jQuery to swap images from text link like working image link

Tags: jquery, image, swap

I have some images that have a jquery function to swap images when the user puts their mouse over them. For instance the following working function swaps area_03.gif with area_03-over.gif and back again as the user moves their mouse off the image. I would also like to place some text links that also roll over the respective images, any ideas how?

EDIT: "The image swap function is working already with the function I provided. The **issue** I am having is getting the **text links swap** to work"

```
 HTML:
<!--Links --> <a href="">Another Link</a>
        <a href="nodes1-nodes21.shtml">Nodes 1 to 21</a>
        <a href="venders1-nodes5.shtml">Venders 1 to 5</a>


<!-- Images -->
        <a href="nodes1-nodes21.shtml" >
            <img class="forhover" src="images/area_03.gif" alt="Link Nodes 1 to 21" width="45" height="27"  id="area_03" />
        </a>

        <a href="venders1-nodes5.shtml" >
            <img class="forhover" src="images/area_05.gif" alt="Link Venders 1 to 5" width="45" height="27"  id="area_05" />
        </a>



Working jquery


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.forhover').each(function(){
    var t=$(this);
    var src1= t.attr('src'); // initial src
    var newSrc = src1.substring(0, src1.lastIndexOf('.'));; // let's get file name without extension
    t.hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc+ '-over.' + /[^.]+$/.exec(src1)); //last part is for extension   
        }, function(){
    $(this).attr('src', newSrc + '.' + /[^.]+$/.exec(src1)); //removing '-over' from the name
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you could manage it with the jquery mouseenter and mouseleave functions

Comment: Does this help with the text links? like I said, the image swap function is working, it is getting the text links swap to work.

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave should work just as well on text links just like they work on everything else.  If you then have those call functions, and the functions identify the image that needs to be changed (say, by id) then there's no reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for the image, but not the text.

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg" hoverImg="http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg">
```

JS:

```
$('body').find('*[hoverImg]').each(function(index){
    $this = $(this)
    $this.wrap('<div>')     
    $this.parent().css('width',$this.width())  
    $this.parent().css('height',$this.width())
    $this.parent().css('background-image',"url(" + $this.attr('hoverImg')+")")
        $this.hover(function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',.01)    
        },function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',1)             
        })                    
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the real issue I am having is with the text links getting to swap the images.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it didn't work for me. I get the following error:

Error: Attribute hoverimg not allowed on element img at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .text() jQuery function in the `<a>` element?

Comment: No, I am not sure how this will help?